# pass value of aspx dropdown list to a separate c# file

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following code snippet inside doc1.aspx:

```
<select id="ListBoxViewType" style="width:160px;font-family:Tahoma;visibility:hidden;">
                        <option value="abcd">Amendment</option>
                        <option value="dcba">Full Terms Amendment</option>
                        <option value="Both">Both</option>
                    </select>
```

On a separate c# file (not the one with aspx.cs), I need to get the value of ListBoxViewType for my if statement. Here's the pseudocode for it:

```
if( listboxviewtype.value == "abcd")
{//do code here}
else
{//do code here}
```

TIA! :)

P.S.
I forgot to mention that the .aspx file and the .cs file where I need to pass the value are in different projects.

Comment: How do you get from one page to the next?  If it's a [cross page post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx), you'll need to use the `PreviousPage` property.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you can accomplish this saving the `<select>` selected value in a session variable.

This forum topic provides concise info about session variables: http://forums.asp.net/t/1140819.aspx/1

Basically, you treat them like they're always there, assigning and reading from them like it was a normal string array.

Answer (score 0):

in your apsx.cs file you can define an eventhandler for the valuechanged or selectedindex/item changed event, you can pass the value to the other class this way. again, you can use a custom event to do this or just call the method while passing the value without accessing the listbox from that seperate c# file.